# Convolutional Neural Network Memory Usage

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a CNN. Suppose there are 1000000 training examples, and one of my layers has dimensions 20x30x30.

Now suppose I have to calculate the training accuracy of these examples. Then, in forward propagation, I would need to store 1000000x20x30x30 = 18 billion values for that layer, which takes up way too much memory. On the other hand, if I do forward propagation on each training example separately, it would take too long.

I was just wondering how I might fix this issue?

Thank you very much for everything!

Comment: Welcome to the central dilemma of computation: time-memory tradeoffs. In this sort of scenario improving one generally means sacrificing the other; the best way to improve it would be to find a completely separate method that's got a better balance, or to improve the efficiency of one of your components. Dunno if that's possible here, though, just thought I'd chime in.

Comment: More detail on your framework, code, setup, etc. is needed, but in general you should be splitting up your training examples into [batches](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network) - you definitely don't want to initialize a 1000000x20x30x30 tensor in whatever framework you're using. Changing the batch size generally trades off between time and memory - feeding in more images at a time lets your neural net framework do more uninterrupted calculations, at the cost of needing to store more images and intermediate layers in memory.

Comment: I tried splitting the training examples into batches and it is working better, thank you for all your help!

I was wondering though, how come feeding in more images at a time is significantly more efficient than running the forward propagation on each training example? Why will uninterrupted calculations make such a huge difference? Since in the end, the calculations are the same. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

What you encounter here is classically solved by batching (as discussed in the comments).
Instead of passing throuh all training examples, you would simply sample a subset of datapoints, and then update your weights after only looking at these few examples. 
The name for this is "Stochastic Gradient Descent" (SGD) compared to vanilla "Gradient Descent" (GD). The stochasticity comes from using a *random subsample* (generally some power of 2, i.e. 4, 8, 16, 32,...).
Now, instead of doing simply an iteration, we differe between an epoch (passing through all of the training data), and a simple iteration (simply using `batch_size` elements)

This also answers part of the question you stated in the comments ("why is it more efficient to feed more images at a time?"):
Since you are updating the weights after each batch (and thus have to compute the backpropagation through your network), it will take longer to get to the next forward pass.

Generally, SGD is also preferred to get better convergence. In practice, it might yield you better results to go with a lot of smaller steps, than take one large one. For more reference, see the last few slides in [this great lecture](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2018/slides/lec08.pdf).

Since you are worried about it taking to long: SGD with a decent batch size (I personally would not even go beyond 2^10 samples per batch; a few papers have "set the standard" of around 128 samples) can get you good results/convergence pretty quickly. You sacrifice the speed of a single iteration for a potentially faster convergence.